# Task indicates IsCompleted even though it is just awaiting

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library

I have the following example code. The problem is, that the `Task` indicates `IsCompleted` even though it just `await`.

`longTask` only `await`s (Task.Delay()) and is not yet finished, so why is `IsCompleted` true? `longTask` can't every be completed, because it is caught in `while(true)`?!

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Task longTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            long count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("doing hard work.");
            while (count < 99999999)
            {
                count++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("wait for a moment");
            await Task.Delay(1000);   
            Console.WriteLine("I have waited enough");
        }
    });

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"status: {longTask.IsCompleted}");
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }

}
```

[image: preview]

Comment: _(not in the example)_ then what are we supposed to help with? In your example task1 is never awaited and task2 starts immediatly as you see in the output.

Comment: I have rewrote the text passage. `longTask` can't every be completed, because it is caught in `while(true)`.

Comment: Nothing waits for `longTask`, all it does is block a separate thread. Besides you shouldn't be using `StartNew` here `Task.Run` is likely what you had in mind especially if your actual project has any type of UI context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `longTask` to represent the inner, never ending, task then call `.Unwrap()` with appropriate settings or use `Task.Run` which has the sensible defaults:

```
public static class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task longTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                long count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("doing hard work.");
                while (count < 99999999)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("wait for a moment");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("I have waited enough");
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach, TaskScheduler.Default).Unwrap();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"status: {longTask.IsCompleted}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

    }
}
```

**or**

```
public static class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task longTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                long count = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("doing hard work.");
                while (count < 99999999)
                {
                    count++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("wait for a moment");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("I have waited enough");
            }
        });
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"status: {longTask.IsCompleted}");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

    }
}
```

For more info: [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) & [Startnew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)